# How to include admin functionality in php script for cpanel cron job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cpanel

I have created a php script which fetch data and post in wordpress and it's running successfully when i hit this script through url in browser but i have to setup this script in cpanel cron job directly but when cron job hit my script i have received my email this.

> Status: 302 Moved Temporarily X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29 Expires: Wed,
>   11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate,
>   max-age=0 Pragma: no-cache Location:
>   http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F&reauth=1
>   Content-type: text/html

This redirect me to login because in my script i have include this two files and without `wp-admin/admin.php` my script not posting data.

```
include('../../../wp-load.php');
include('../../../wp-admin/admin.php');
```

And since two days i am researching so many things wp-cron.php disable wordpress cron and run real cron through cpanel but i have design my php script like external not like plugin and further more research i have found `wp-admin/admin-functions.php` will run all posts and taxonomy function for posting and not force to login but it is not happening i have also tried this but my script is not running.

```
include('../../../wp-load.php');
include('../../../wp-admin/admin-functions.php');
```

After this i have research more and i got an idea to include wp-includes/post.php and wp-includes/taxonomy.php becasue my script have `wp_insert_post , wp_insert_attachment, wp_set_object_terms and wp_insert_terms functions etc` but its also redirect me to login

please help me now i am tired and this stackoverflow is my last hope please help me thank you in advance...

Comment: please guide me how can i do this i want to run my script through cron job please help me

Comment: I am shock i have posted this question about 8 hours ago but no one answer me :( why please guide i need a help